# GCP Google Cloud Storage: avoid expensive data transfer out network egress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to make cheap backups to Google Cloud Storage 
that I hopefully will never retrieve back, 
but just in case I wanna know whether it's possible 
to avoid expensive network egress (data transfer) out of GCP.

According to https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing 
it's **$0.12 per 1 GB** which is huge.

There's a competitor (AWS Glacier Deep Archive) 
which theoretically allows to transfer bucket contents for free with VPC peering
to any instance in the same region 
e.g. AWS Lightsail with monthly out-bandwidth **up to a few TB**.

Or at least AWS free tier proposes **50GB/month CDN for free** in the first year (and again transfer data from bucket to CDN is free).

Is there something similar in GCP?

Answer (score 1):

Network egress costs you see on the [GCS pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) page are for the **outbound** traffic from the GCS.

> Network usage charges apply when object data or object metadata is
>   read from your Cloud Storage buckets.

Writing files to a GCS bucket shouldn't affect the egress cost (only reading them).

Since in your scenario you are not planning to access the stored data frequently, for the backups I’d recommend you to take a look into [Archival Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#archive), the GCP’s [alternative](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws) to the Amazon Glacier.

## EDIT

Basically, the GCS pricing page covers the available pricing options and [free quota](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free).

While the network egress does offer free rates in some [circumstances](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets), since you have read that documentation page already, I assume that those options are not suitable/applicable for your use case. Therefore, I'd recommend you to contact GCP [Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to explore if there is any other option available for your particular situation.

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to avoid - expensive retrieval :) is there any method as it is for AWS?

Comment: @Xitroff Thanks for pointing that out, I believe I misread the question at first:) I have updated the answer.